# TS get variable type

Tags: typescript

I would like to get variable type to give it to a class param.

```
certificate: CertificationInterface;

certificate = new CertificationFactory().create(param.type, {id: param.id});

helperService = new HelperFactoryService<certificate>().get();
```

The third line not working.

Comment: `typeof certificate`?

Comment: it's return with string, not good

Comment: `helperService = new HelperFactoryService<typeof certificate>().get();`

Answer (score 1):

You could try to use the interface.

```
new HelperFactoryService<CertificationInterface>().get();
```

Answer (score 0):

TypeScript types are erased during compilation (except for classes). What you can get is object constructor and use it a a type.

In you case `param.constructor` will give you some function that is a constructor (class) of your param.

`param instanceof param.constructor)` will evaluate to `true`.